# when setting a property does the property name always change to camelcase?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

So if a have this property:

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder;

and i want to set it, does the case always change:

[self setReverseGeocoder:  ...

Seems a bit weird to get used to!  I mean the property name is lower case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because that's the convention for naming setters/getters for [Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/Compliant.html#)